# Using tf.random.set_seed but still getting an error no attribute 'set_random_seed'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, random-seed

I'm trying to set seed using `tf.random.set_seed` instead of `tf.set_random_seed`, but still getting the error as module `'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'`

Trying to run this:

```
def __init__(self, log_name, heatmap_size, image_size, loss_type = 'SCE', is_training = True):
        tf.random.set_seed(0)
```

But getting the error:

```
28
29 
def __init__(self, log_name, heatmap_size, image_size, loss_type = 'SCE', is_training = True):
---> 30         tf.random.set_seed(0)
     31 
     32         if loss_type not in { 'MSE', 'SCE' }:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'
```

Comment: What is your tensorflow version? You are using `random.set_seed(0)` in your function but you are getting ` 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'` Error?

Comment: @Goku im using tensorflow version 2.15 and trying to use tf.random.set_seed(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Tensorflow 2.15 you can use:

```
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(
    seed
)
```

Link to document : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed

Comment: still has the same error: 29     def __init__(self, log_name, heatmap_size, image_size, loss_type = 'SCE', is_training = True):
---> 30         tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(0)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'

Comment: Try to create a new virtual environment and install `tensorflow` afresh